# How to aggregate columns as well as rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

`listagg` works as expected for `poll_id=2`.

How can I accomlish the same for one row  and multiple columns?

```
with list_of_fruits as
(select  1 as poll_id ,'Apple' as first_choice, 'Pear' as second_choice, 'Peach' as third_choice, 'Plum' as fourth_choice from dual union all
select  2 as poll_id ,'Cherry' as first_choice, null as second_choice, null as third_choice, null as fourth_choice from dual union all
select  2 as poll_id ,'Grape' as first_choice, null as second_choice, null as third_choice, null as fourth_choice from dual union all
select  2 as poll_id ,'Kiwi' as first_choice, null as second_choice, null as third_choice, null as fourth_choice from dual union all
select  3 as poll_id ,'Squash' as first_choice, 'Peas' as second_choice, '' as third_choice, null as fourth_choice from dual union all
select  3 as poll_id ,null as first_choice, null as second_choice, null as third_choice, 'Barley' as fourth_choice from dual union all
select  3 as poll_id ,null as first_choice, null as second_choice, 'Oats' as third_choice, null as fourth_choice from dual

)    select poll_id, listagg(first_choice,';') within group (order by poll_id) as sam
    from list_of_fruits
    group by poll_id
```

**Desired Output**

Consolodate all rows and columns (left to right, top to bottom) so that each poll_id has only one row in the result set. I want to ignore nulls.

```
1 Apple;Pear;Peach;Plum
2 Cherry;Grape;Kiwi
3 Squash;Peas;Barley;Oats
```

Comment: In your example, for `poll_id = 2`, all three fruits are "`first_choice`". In what order should they appear in the output? (Does it matter? For example, they can appear in alphabetical order.) Otherwise, I assume for any given `poll_id` the fruits given in `first_choice` should appear first, then those in `second_choice` etc.?

Comment: Yes order does matter. For each id, go  1st,2nd,3rd,4th choice. Then 2nd row , then third row. etc..

Comment: @zundarz I updated my answer below.

Comment: Your data is not normalized, and while the @mathguy solution might give you the result you want, a better approach would be to change your database design to avoid storing data as CSV.

Comment: What do you mean by "first row", "second row" etc.? Rows in a table are not ordered. Do you have another column to order the rows by that column? Or do you mean "arbitrary" row order, but the fruits should be read from each row and then skip to another row?

Comment: Good point. What is important is 1st, 2nd,3rd,4th for each row. Since the rows could be in any order per_id, I'll be content with just getting columns first and row_id order being random.

Comment: OK, then I will revise my solution.

Comment: @tim, agree about data not being normalized. However, this is an extract of massive ERP and I'm stuck with their design against which I've got to report. Thanks for taking time to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with
     list_of_fruits 
            ( poll_id, first_choice, second_choice, third_choice, fourth_choice ) as (
       select  1,'Apple' , 'Pear', 'Peach', 'Plum'   from dual union all
       select  2,'Cherry', ''    , ''     , ''       from dual union all
       select  2,'Grape' , ''    , 'Berry', ''       from dual union all
       select  2,'Kiwi'  , ''    , ''     , ''       from dual union all
       select  3,'Squash', 'Peas', ''     , ''       from dual union all
       select  3,''      , ''    , ''     , 'Barley' from dual union all
       select  3,''      , ''    , 'Oats' , ''       from dual
     ),
     prep ( poll_id, first_choice, second_choice, third_choice, fourth_choice, rn ) as (
       select poll_id, first_choice, second_choice, third_choice, fourth_choice,
              row_number() over (partition by poll_id order by null)
       from list_of_fruits
     )
select poll_id, listagg(fruit, ',') within group (order by rn, choice) as sam
from prep
unpivot ( fruit for choice in (first_choice as 1, second_choice as 2, 
                                             third_choice as 3, fourth_choice as 4))
group by poll_id
order by poll_id  -- ORDER BY is optional
;


   POLL_ID SAM
---------- ------------------------------
         1 Apple,Pear,Peach,Plum
         2 Grape,Berry,Cherry,Kiwi
         3 Squash,Peas,Barley,Oats
```

Comment: Notice `order by null` in `row_number()` in the definition of `rn` in `prep`. This means rows for a given `poll_id` will be in arbitrary order, but they will be in **some** order. If they must be in a more specific order, that can be adjusted in the `order by` clause in `row_number`. Also, I changed the CTEs to have the column names right after the CTE name. This works only in Oracle 11.2 and above; for 11.1, you can move the column names back inside the CTE definition (as you had them initially), and do the same for `prep`.

Comment: I also added `'Berry'` as a `third_choice` in one of the rows for `poll_id = 2` to test if the solution works correctly.